# Trying let user upload files to my website but there are some errors

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Here is my HTML code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="new1.php" method="POST">
    Choose File: <input name="userfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

And this is my PHP code :

```
<?php
   $path = "files/";
   $path = $path.basename( $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
       echo "Success uploading". basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
   } else{
       echo "Error when uploading file.";
   }
?>
```

Here are the errors I got when running on XAMPP

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(files/ChicKissLove.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\new1.php on line 7

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpAF97.tmp' to 'files/ChicKissLove.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\phptest\new1.php on line 7
Error when uploading file.
```

Anyone can find out what's wrong ?
I 'm unable to upload the files.

Comment: try to create files directory first

Comment: The error message told you what was wrong. Tip: Google error messages. It may surprise you, but most of the time it brings up results advising how to fix such errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create files directory in the same directory where your code is first. And You are good to go.

P.S next time save your files with a random name because someone else might upload a file with same name creating more problems and always filter your uploading files never allow executable files.

Comment: Thank you. I have created a file directory with the same name as $path = "files/". Is it a must to do so ?

Comment: you can create files directory using code as well provided you have the right permissions, what is must to do? Creating files directory or the extra stuff i mentioned, creating files directory is must because how can you save a file in a directory, without that directory existing? as far as those extra things i mentioned they are not must to do but for security reasons they are `must to do`.

Comment: and having random named files help you keep every files otherwise users might upload files with same name and you will lose previous files because you can a a single file with unique name right?

Answer (score 0):

Create `files` folder in the respective section or use below code, it will create directory automatically.

```
$path = "files/";   
if(!is_dir($path)){
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be **two** possibilities:
**Either** there is no directory with name **files** where the images could be stored
**Or** the path to the directory is wrong. the directory should be in the same place where your **new1.php** resides
and `last but not the least`
Note:-**do not forget to give the required permissions to the directory**